# Как отправить письмо при ручном добавлении транзакции в Магазин/Покупатели/Транзакции в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет!
Есть сайт на 1с-битрикс.
При покупке товаров и прочих действиях клиенту начисляются бонусы, о чем приходит письмо с описанием начисления и суммой. Но если добавлять бонусы вручную в разделе Магазин/Покупатели/Транзакции, то письма не приходят. Событий на это не нашел, обработчик повесить не могу. Думал. чтобы повесить обработчик на изменение инфоблока, но является ли эта таблица с транзакциями инфоблоком. Если да, то как узнать ее id? Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: В разделе "Настройка" найдите почтовый шаблон, который отправляется при начислении бонусов. Посмотрите какое событие вызывает этот шаблон и привязывайтесь к этому событию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Пользуйтесь на здоровье:

```
<?
AddEventHandler("sale", "OnAfterUserAccountUpdate", "AfterUserAccountUpdate");

function AfterUserAccountUpdate($accountId)
{
    $userAccountId = +$accountId;//id счета покупателя
    $arNewAccountData = CSaleUserAccount::GetByID($userAccountId);//данные счета покупателя
    $userId = +$arNewAccountData["USER_ID"];//id покупателя
    $timestampX = $arNewAccountData["TIMESTAMP_X"];//дата время изменения счета
    $mailEvent = "BONUS_EVENT";//почтовое событие

    $rsMess = CEventMessage::GetList($by="id", $order="desc", ["EVENT_NAME" => $mailEvent]);
    while($arMess = $rsMess->GetNext())
    {
        $siteId = $arMess["SITE_ID"];//id сайта
    }

    $rsTransact = CSaleUserTransact::GetList(
        Array(),
        Array("USER_ID" => $userId, "TRANSACT_DATE" => $timestampX, "DEBIT" => "Y", "DESCRIPTION" => "MANUAL")
    );
    $arItems = $rsTransact->Fetch();//массив только ручного добавления баллов через транзакцию

    if($arItems)
    {
        $rsUser = CUser::GetByID($arItems["USER_ID"]);
        $arUser = $rsUser->Fetch();
        $toSend["USER"] = $arUser["NAME"];
        $toSend["EMAIL"] = $arUser["EMAIL"];
        $toSend["DATE_ADD_BONUS"] = $arItems["TIMESTAMP_X"];
        $toSend["COUNT_BONUS"] = +$arItems["AMOUNT"];
        $toSend["ORDER_ID"] = ($arItems["ORDER_ID"])? $arItems["ORDER_ID"] : "" ;
        CEvent::SendImmediate($mailEvent, $siteId, $toSend);
    }
}

?>
```